# how to attach attachment to mail and download it

Tags: linux

how can attachment sends through mail command in linux 
with mail command 
either with mail -s or -v option 
also how please confirm how to download the attachments from it . 
and how one should knows with mail command that attachment is present with the particular mail

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are not very clear.

I don't think the "mail" command can attach files to an e-mail.  There are other commands that can do it, though.  e.g. the mutt command can do it.

`mutt -s "This is the subject" -a /path/to/file recipient@example.com`

For extracting the attachments from a message, again something like mutt or pine would probably be better.

What exactly are you trying to do?  Read and send mail interactively from the command line?  From a script?

Answer (score 0):

depends on which version of mail are you using.
In later linux release, mail actually refers to mailx, which you can use the -a option directly